# Something like theories @TestedOn but usable with Strings? or separate parameterized classes?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, junit4

I have a couple different arrays of strings, such as

```
private static final String[] allowed = {"-", "_", "@", ".", "`", "[", "]", "'", "#", "?", "&", "!", "{", "}"};
private static final String[] disallowed = {" ",  "/", "*", "~", "|","\\", "<", ">", "\"", "=", "%", "$", "^"};
```

and I have three tests that test creating users, lets call them Test A, B, and C.

If I want to run Test A separately against every string in `allowed`, Test B against every String in `disallowed`, and Test C has no parameters and just runs, is there a way to do all three in one class or do i need to have them broken apart in to separate classes(Currently Test A, B and C are in separate classes)?

I was looking into Junits theories and there looks like some possibility but theories is fairly undocumented which leads me to here.  Thanks for any pointers or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a library on GitHub in which I implemented `@TestOn` which allows for all the primitive types.

[TestOn](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/master/testlibex/src/main/java/org/libex/test/theories/suppliers/TestOn.java)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO [@FromDataPoints](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/experimental/theories/FromDataPoints.html) can help you.

```
@DataPoints ("allowed")
private static final String[] allowed = {"-", ... }

@DataPoints ("disallowed ")
private static final String[] disallowed = {" ", ... }

@Theory
public void testAllowed(@FromDataPoints("allowed") String s) { ... }

@Theory
public void testDisallowed(@FromDataPoints("disallowed") String s) { ... }
```